# How to vertically align the child divs in a parent div?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

So I have 1 parent div and 4 child divs. I have horizontally aligned those child divs in the parent div, however they are not vertically aligned, it's like a graph the way the child divs are placed.
How do I vertically align them?

```css
.servicesContent {
  border: solid red 2px;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.servicesH1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #3a414e;
}
.servicesContent h2 {
  color: #3a414e;
}
#h3 {
  color: #3a414e;
}
.contentLists {
  border: solid green 2px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#lists {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="servicesContent">
  <h1 class="servicesH1">Services</h1>
  <h2>Help!</h2>
  <p>Child Divs are not vertically aligned</p>
  <p>Help</p>

  <div class="contentLists">
    <div id="lists">
      <h3 id="h3">first</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>afasasf</li>
        <li>fasfsafas</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="lists">
      <h3 id="h3">second</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>gdagadg</li>
        <li>agadgadg</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="lists">
      <h3 id="h3">third</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>dsfdsfs</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="lists">
      <h3 id="h3">fourth</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>dagadg</li>
        <li>agadgdhtjrs</li>
        <li>jjee</li>
        <li>ejtejtjejejgfhdgh</li>
        <li>Gtejjtejejtds</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: In passing, I note that you have several elements with the conflicting ID (3x `lists` and 3x `h3`).  You'll want to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 #lists {
                  display: inline-block;
                  text-align: center;
                  padding: 5px;
                  margin: 5px;
                  border: 1px solid blue;
                  height: 190px;
             vertical-align: middle;
                }
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Please do try to add `vertical-align: top;` as like below

```
 #lists {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 190px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to align elements in the new browsers is the use of Flexbox. With justify-content center all element of the contentLists will be aligned horizontally and with align-items: center they'll be aligned vertically too. for more info about Flexbox, please check this out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.contentLists {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
```